# Factory pattern with parameters

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am using the JDBC connector for my log4j output and want to post my log entries to a Postgres database. This looks as follows:

```
<Jdbc name="Jdbc" tableName="log">
    <ConnectionFactory class="database.ConnectionFactory" method="getConnection"/>
    <Column name="event_date" isEventTimestamp="true" />
    <Column name="level" pattern="%level" isUnicode="false" />
    <Column name="logger" pattern="%logger" isUnicode="false" />
    <Column name="message" pattern="%message" isUnicode="false" />
     <Column name="exception" pattern="%ex{full}" isUnicode="false" />
</Jdbc>
```

As far as I understand this requires a static class with the method `getConnection` and I implemented this using the factory pattern:

```
public class ConnectionFactory {
    private static interface Singleton {
        final ConnectionFactory INSTANCE = new ConnectionFactory();
    }

    private ComboPooledDataSource comboPooledDataSource;

    private ConnectionFactory() {
        comboPooledDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        try {
            // Load the jdbc driver.
            comboPooledDataSource.setDriverClass("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (PropertyVetoException exception) {

        }

        // Need to create datasource here, requires parameters.
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return Singleton.INSTANCE.comboPooledDataSource.getConnection();
    }
}
```

My problem is, that I want to create the connection to the database via parameters (host, port, database, etc.) and do not want to hard-code it. Also having a static class which holds the configuration would not be preferred because I would like to be able to unit test it easily.

What is a good solution to achieve this? Am I maybe overlooking something or is this a bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

Factory methods can take parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While this is true in general, I will have a connection pool in this case which I don't want to recreate every time I call `getConnection()` because this would break the whole pool concept. Therefore I don't think that I should be passing the parameters to creating the connection pool into this method.

Answer (score -1):

Using reflection and Enumeration can help:
I have already implemented something like this for myself:

```
public class BusFactory {

public IBus createBus(BusType busType, String busUrl) {

    try {

        if(busType == null){
            return null;
        }

        //Touraj: Get Bus By Reflection

        Class<?> busClass = Class.forName(busType.getFullQualifiedName());
        Constructor con = busClass.getConstructor(String.class);

        Object busObj = con.newInstance(busUrl);

        if (busObj instanceof ETCDBus) {

            return (ETCDBus)busObj;

        } else if (busObj instanceof AeroSpikeBus) {

            return (AeroSpikeBus)busObj;

        }else
        {
            throw new UnsupportedBusException("this Type of Bus is not Supported");
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedBusException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

and BusType is like this:

```
public enum BusType {

ETCD("BUS.ETCDBus"),
AEROSPIKE("AEROSPIKE"),
RAIMA("RAIMA"),
HANA("HANA"),
GEODE("GEODE"),
IGNITE("IGNITE"),
SENTINEL("SENTINEL"),
REDIS("BUS.RedisBus"),
Informix("Informix");

private String fullQualifiedName;

BusType(String fullQualifiedName) {
    this.fullQualifiedName = fullQualifiedName;
}

public String getFullQualifiedName() {
    return fullQualifiedName;
}

}
```